# Can I check a file's properties before saving it with system_retrieve_file?

Tags: files

My understanding of `system_retrieve_file` is that it saves the file temporarily first. Is it possible to check this file and if it passes, then save it?

I've only used this function like below.

```
$image = 'http://.jpg';
$file = system_retrieve_file($image, 'public://images/', TRUE, $replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the file "properties" you're wanting to check here.

The file contents? Sure. You can invoke `$result = drupal_http_request($url);`(7) or `\Drupal::httpClient()->get($url)->getBody();`(8) ahead of time to inspect the HTTP contents before calling `system_retrieve_file()`.

The file entity properties (or the temporary file created before moving to `$destination`)? No (without replicating/modifying some core functionality). There are no open hooks to that before `system_retrieve_file()` commits to saving that data to filesystem/DB.